# Authorize attribute in dot net core controller protected by oidc

Tags: javascript, cors, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have MVC dot Net Core app 2.0. The App authenticates against IdentityServer4 using  Hybrid grant, so I have:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
o.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
o.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{......
```

and this works fine.

I also have a JavaScript client which authenticates against same IDP using implicit grant and that also works fine.  I wanted to allow the javascript client calling an API (controller inside the MVC app) passing bearer token.
If that API has an Authorize attribute I am getting:
Failed to load http://localhost:4444/testidentity: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5003
I have CORS taking care off and the call works if I do not require Authorization at the API controller level.

I can easily move API into a separate project and  having in the API something like:

```
services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
{.......
```

This would work, but I would like to have it working in the MVC app and apparently missing some middleware configuration.

Comment: It's worth posting request/response headers, because it's not clear if your CORS is actually properly configured.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your MVC app using openid bearer and cookies authentication, make sure to have the API (controller in MVC app) authentication schema as "bearer" then it will look for a bearer token in the request (regardless whose calling the API passing your CORS policy defined for your app) and verifies as per your middleware configuration for bearer token validation.

Also make sure, the access token has MVC app required scope to call controller.

I guess you will need something like below

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = 
    JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

For more information refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are making a [HttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is *[Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)*.

Quoted from *[Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)*:

> Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.

Identityserver 4 needs to be configured for CORS.  I suspect you need to add something like this [Allowing Ajax calls to the Web API with CORS](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/7_javascript_client.html#allowing-ajax-calls-to-the-web-api-with-cors)